# Translate date format

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I have the following piece of PHP that loops through my wordpress posts:

```
<?php
    $items = 0;
    $thiscat = get_category(2);
    $cat_slug = $thiscat->slug;
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'Course', 
        'category_name' => $cat_slug,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() AND $items < 3) {
        $loop->the_post();
        $category_course = get_the_category(2);
        $cat_slug_course = $category_course[0]->slug;
        $date_start = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'date_start', true);
        $place = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "place", true);
        $date_start = date("D, M d, Y", $date_start);
        if( strtotime($date_start) >= strtotime('today') ) { ?>
            <li>                            
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="date_fp"><?php echo $date_start; ?> - <?php echo $place; ?></a>
            </li>
<?php $items++; }
    }
    if($items==0) { ?>
        <li>                            
            Ingen kommende kurser
        </li>
<?php } ?>
```

It loops and displays up to three start dates for courses. However, I want `$date_start` to output in Danish, instead of English.

I tried replacing date with [strftime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) and tried to set [locale](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) to Danish, but in some way, when changing the date format to strftime (%a, %d %b, %Y), my loop just outputs `Ingen kommende kurser` (No future courses). This is weird, because when working with date (and getting the English output), there is a course date being displayed.

$date_start outputs the time in milliseconds (e.g. `1371081600137535`)

A solution I tried, but didn't work:

```
...
$place = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "place", true);
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');
$date_start = strftime("%a, %d %b, %Y", mktime($date_start));
if( strtotime($date_start) >= strtotime('today') ) { ?>
...
```

Comment: Are you sure the desired locale is installed on your system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make double date conversion: 1) timestamp to text; 2) text to timestamp. Whereas you don't need any conversion. You can simply use timestamp obtained by `get_post_meta` in `if` statement.
Also `setlocale` only affect to formatting, not to timezones. If you want apply Danish timezone, you have to call `date_default_timezone_set`.

Try this:

```
    ...
    $date_start = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'date_start', true);
    $place = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "place", true);
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');
    if( $date_start >= strtotime('today') ) {
        ...                        
        echo date("D, M d, Y", $date_start);
        ...                        
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the date value is being incorrectly translated due to time zone differences.

try something like

```
// $date_start is already a timestamp so do not do conversion
// $date_start = date("D, M d, Y", $date_start);
if( $date_start >= strtotime('today') ) { ?>
<li>                            
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="date_fp"><?php echo date("D, M d, Y", $date_start); ?> - <?php echo $place; ?></a>
</li>
<?php $items++; }
```

This code avoids converting the date for calculations, but will do so for display.